# Can't deploy the project on Tomcat 6.0

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I have here a Web application being written in Java. Spring Web MVC is part of it. NetBeans 7.0 IDE being used. I deployed the  app on Tomcat 6.0, it worked. Then I did it again, so since then it is undeploying the project. I can't stop the process using Stop/build command on NetBeans. I restarted the server but that did not help. And this issue is taking place for a while. Restart of computer helps.
What is the problem?
Best regards

Comment: Your question is very vague and uninformative. Please provide us with stack traces/error messages or something more not requiring us to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably an IDE/plugin issue interacting with the server process. Eclipse suffers from the same issues. Just restart your IDE and accept your fate.

Comment: Or get IntelliJ - it works seamlessly with Tomcat, no plugin needed.

Comment: true dat, I had no experience with IntelliJ in 2011